# How can I build an HTML5 liquid mixing animation?

Tags: html, animation, cordova, html5-canvas, webgl

A few years ago I built a small OpenGL project where I simulated an animation of mixing liquids; a similar project can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx2blmfmAgo) or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwgujC3LkMs&feature=related) (these are 2 youtube videos showing some liquid animations).

My main purpose is to simulate these animations using webGL, JS, CSS or HTML5 in order to use them with Phonegap.

In my project I have set 2 main liquids with different density and different colors in order to test the mixture process. My main goal is to animate the flowing of the 2 liquids and start mixing when the user starts shaking his smartphone (or when the user clicks a button, if we are in a web based application).

During my research, I have collected several physics papers explaining the process. Also I have seen several libraries like [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), but I am not quite sure which one is better, or where to start, and which one is compatible with Phonegap. Any suggestions, links or references will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent Javascript library wrapping the `webgl` functionality, called [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).

Comment: As I can see, from the examples it's an awesome libary